# Use distinct in nested query returns different results

Tags: sql, distinct

I tried two queries, one with `distinct`, one without `distinct`, and I get two different results. What could be the possible reason? The one without `DISTINCT` seems to be the correct answer, but why are the results different?

Another confusing part is if I save the subqueries as two intermediate tables and do `count(distinct)`, I was able to get the same results. Same as the one without `DISTINCT` in my first two queries.

Here are my two queries

```
SELECT 
    tmp.year, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(tmp.encounter_id)) AS Nencounter,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(tmp.patient_sk)) AS Npatient
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         fe.encounter_id, dd.year, dp.patient_sk
     FROM
         cerner_db.f_encounter fe
     JOIN
         cerner_db.d_date dd ON fe.admitted_dt_id = dd.date_id
     JOIN
         cerner_db.d_patient dp ON dp.patient_id = fe.patient_id) tmp
GROUP BY 
    year
ORDER BY 
    year;
```

Second one

```
SELECT 
    tmp.year, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(tmp.encounter_id)) AS Nencounter,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(tmp.patient_sk)) AS Npatient
FROM 
    (SELECT
         fe.encounter_id, dd.year, dp.patient_sk
     FROM
         cerner_db.f_encounter fe
     JOIN
         cerner_db.d_date dd ON fe.admitted_dt_id = dd.date_id
     JOIN
         cerner_db.d_patient dp ON dp.patient_id = fe.patient_id) tmp
GROUP BY 
    year
ORDER BY 
    year;
```

Results:

[image]

If I run intermediate tables and query, I get the same results

```
--try1
CREATE TABLE cerner_bds_db.overall STORED as PARQUET AS
SELECT tmp.year, count(distinct(tmp.encounter_id)) as Nencounter, count(distinct(tmp.patient_sk)) as Npatient
FROM (
    select DISTINCT fe.encounter_id, dd.year, dp.patient_sk
    from cerner_db.f_encounter fe
    join cerner_db.d_date dd on fe.admitted_dt_id=dd.date_id
    join cerner_db.d_patient dp on dp.patient_id=fe.patient_id) tmp
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year;

--try2
CREATE TABLE cerner_bds_db.overall STORED as PARQUET AS
SELECT tmp.year, count(distinct(tmp.encounter_id)) as Nencounter, count(distinct(tmp.patient_sk)) as Npatient
FROM (
    select fe.encounter_id, dd.year, dp.patient_sk
    from cerner_db.f_encounter fe
    join cerner_db.d_date dd on fe.admitted_dt_id=dd.date_id
    join cerner_db.d_patient dp on dp.patient_id=fe.patient_id) tmp
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year;

select year, count(DISTINCT(patient_sk)) from try1 GROUP BY year;
select year, count(DISTINCT(patient_sk)) from try2 GROUP BY year;
```

[image]

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using hive to do this

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that your first query is selecting distinct values whereas your second query is not selecting distinct values, which returns possible duplicates - it's simple as that.

Regarding the count distinct: I can't tell which table is generated from which query based on the picture alone, but I would expect that counting values from a distinct query would return a smaller value than counting values from a non-distinct query.

Comment: It is exactly opposite around.  The pic on left is from 1st query, right from 2nd query.  That's why im so confused.

Answer (score 0):

You're reducing the queries in different places with different levels of `DISTINCT`, this type of behavior should be expected if your data is kind of wonky.

`select DISTINCT fe.encounter_id, ...`

But this is a sub-Select query and the main Select also has a `Distinct` filter, but the primary results are reduced by the subquery's initial filter. That `Distinct` criteria filters the entire row, while the primary query only filters based on the specific column.

The sub-Query with the Distinct will remove *all rows* that are the exactly same and that is the expected result. The problem here is that your first query is selecting distinct values, but your second query is **not** pulling specific distinct **values**, therefore your result will pull in possible duplicates without the distinct. To be completely honest here, this is most likely a problem with the way the data structured if you are having this many duplicate problems.

A *big* part of what you are probably seeing is due in part to the DISTINCT while the GROUP is affecting the initial data that is being pulled. But still, this is to be expected the way that these queries are currently written.

Comment: What I want my subquery distinct to do is deduplicate rows, while main query distinct to filters on column.  It doesn't make sense to me the deduplicated case generate more count

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` works in two different ways, and you are using both:

- In the inner/subquery you are applying `DISTINCT` **to the full row**, not each column separately. Therefore, the subquery may return duplicate values for `encounter_id` and `patient_sk`. It only eliminates duplicate **row** combinations.
- In the outer query you count `DISTINCT` **column** values, when you apply it to each column separately.

Of course you will find differences.

It happens that the first column gives you the same result, and the second one a different one. But in general, you would normally get different results in both columns.

Comment: But wasn't I suppose to have fewer rows from subquery if I use Distinct?  How come I get more?  Also notice my encounter count keeps the same with or without distinct

Answer (score 0):

You are either over or under thinking this. A record can not be a duplicate on an entire row and still not have a unique value in each column.

Look at the query results and subqueries separately and it'll click.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f2315/4

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_DATA
  ( id VARCHAR(100),
    val VARCHAR(100),
    found VARCHAR(100)
  );

INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES (2018,'A','A');
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES (2018,'B','C');
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES (2018,'B','B');
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES (2018,'B','B');
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES (2018,'A','A');
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES (2018,'C','NULL');

SELECT id, 
       COUNT(val),
       COUNT(found)
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id, val, found FROM TEST_DATA) TMP
 GROUP
    BY id;

vs. 

SELECT id, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT(val)),
       COUNT(DISTINCT(found))
  FROM (SELECT id, val, found FROM TEST_DATA) TMP
 GROUP
    BY id
```

Comment: Thank you for your example.  But my two main queries are all count(distinct), if i change that in your code, I got same results.  However, my query results are different

Comment: Hmmm... I guess I'm under thinking this too.

Comment: Weird. It looks like the other answers had the same interpretation as me. My hunch at the moment is some strange NULL behavior in Hive? I'm not able to reproduce this in SQL Server. Unless I'm just being dumb.

Comment: I have similar feeling about the NULL effects here.

Comment: @ZenZen Can you try running both with a NULL filter (ex. WHERE fe.encounter_id IS NOT NULL AND  dd.year IS NOT NULL AND dp.patient_sk IS NOT NULL) and see if you are still getting a difference?

Comment: If I do intermediate tables, problem is gone.  But why

Comment: @ZenZen The explanation for that might be a bit easier. Sometimes duplicates are quietly dropped on table creation to enforce uniqueness (essentially applying distinct). I'm not sure about Hive but in a DB like Teradata CREATE TABLE TEST_DATA AS (SELECT Blah Blah Blah FROM Some_Table); is functionally the same as CREATE TABLE TEST_DATA AS (SELECT DISTINCT Blah Blah Blah FROM Some_Table);

Comment: Weird.  After adding in Where to drop NULL.  I have the same results as before